# Display dropped link in a div and the dropped div will be inner div and clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new in javascript and jquery.
I am working with a self project called **Bookmark** **Visualization** and I need to make dropable link as an inner div and it will be clickable.   I make my div Content Editable.

Html
`<div id="field" contenteditable="true">This is a test #hath</div>`

Style
`#mydiv{ width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid #000; }`

Is there anyone to make me feel great. 
 Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include your code so far and a better explanation of what you're trying to do

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us what you have done so far. Read this before posting questions again please. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `<div id="mydiv" contenteditable="true">This is a test #hath</div> `  Style  
`#mydiv{ width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid #000; }`

there is nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a div clickable by using an a class...

```
HTML
<div id="my-clickable-div"><a href="YOUR LINK HERE" class="my-clickable-div"></a></div>

CSS
#my-clickable-div {position:relative; float:left; width:100%; height:200px; background:#000;}
a.my-clickable-div {display:block; height:100%; width:100%; text-decoration:none;}
```

Comment: Edited answer. Let me know if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry sir. I thik you take it as wrong.
I want to make **dropped link** as a clickable div.

Comment: That is how to make a div clickable. You need to explain what you mean by "dropped link".

Comment: We use **bookmark** bar to save link. Just like bookmark bar I want to make a div where I can store link and that will be clickable.